# How could I dynamically filter a listview control in javafx using the MVC model while is updated in more than one way?

Tags: listview, javafx, textfield, fxml, program-entry-point

I'm using 3 files: View.fxml, Main and Controller.

I found a way to update a listview control with the string that is stored in the clipboard when the clipboard gets updated (when a string is copied).

What I have been unable to achieve is that I also want that same list to be updated/filtered when the user updates a textfield. I'm not sure how to setup the observable list, predicate or in which file, the Main file or in the Controller file.

I add my code:

**Main**

```
import Controller.Controller01;
import Model.Clip;
import Model.ClipboardListener;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.ObjectExpression;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main extends Application  {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader =new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/View/View01.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.setX(200);
        primaryStage.setY(500);
        Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        double x = bounds.getMinX() + (bounds.getWidth() - scene.getWidth()) * 0.2;
        double y = bounds.getMinY() + (bounds.getHeight() - scene.getHeight()) * 0.55;
        primaryStage.setX(x);
        primaryStage.setY(y);


// longrunning operation runs on different thread
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            String oldString = "";
            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("pulse in run 1 ");
                System.out.println("crrent thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());


                Runnable updater = new Runnable() {


                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //updateview();

                    }   //    run   ends ---------------------------------------------------

                };    //    updater   ends ---------------------------------------------------






            }

        });   //  thread runnable ends -------------------------------------------------------
        // don't let thread prevent JVM shutdown
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();





// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //  in main, clipboard listener, I'm unsure how to update the listivew here if the textfield changes
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        final Clipboard systemClipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        new com.sun.glass.ui.ClipboardAssistance(com.sun.glass.ui.Clipboard.SYSTEM) {
            @Override
            public void contentChanged() {

                System.out.print("System clipboard content changed: ");
                if ( systemClipboard.hasImage() ) {
                    System.out.println("image");
                } else if ( systemClipboard.hasString() ) {
                    System.out.println("string");
                    //System.out.println(Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString());
                    System.out.println("current thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());


                   // controller.mylistviewvar.setItems(data);


                    Controller.Controller01 controller = loader.getController();           // works1
                    String fromclipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString();


                    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                    

                    //controller.mylistviewvar.getItems().add(0,fromclipboard);                  // works1


                } else if ( systemClipboard.hasFiles() ) {
                    System.out.println("files");
                }
            }
        };
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println("crrent thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());




    }  // start stage ends --------------------------------------------

    

//  Mythread01   ends -----------------------------------




    public final Controller01 controller = new Controller01();

} // Main ends
```

**Controller**

```
package Controller;

import Model.Clip;
import Model.ClipboardListener;
import com.sun.tools.javac.Main;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Controller01 implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    private Button myButton01;

    @FXML
    public ListView<String> mylistviewvar;

    public void setMylistviewvar(String listviewvar) {
        mylistviewvar.getItems().add(listviewvar);
    }

    @FXML
    void myButton01myEventClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hi there !");


        // to put string INTO clipboard
        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString("Some text");
        clipboard.setContent(content);
        // to copy from clipboard
        String fromclipboardstr = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString();
        System.out.println(fromclipboardstr);


        //  ---------   alert dialogs
//        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
//        alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
//        //alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
//        alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");
//        alert.showAndWait();

//        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
//        alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
//        alert.setHeaderText(null);
//        alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");
//        alert.showAndWait();




    }  // button click ends
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton myToggleBut;


// using this template methods in main can be accessed
//    @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonRegister() throws IOException{
//        //
//        //Here I want to invoke gotoRegister
//        FXMLExampleMVC.getInstance().gotoRegister();
//    }

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane myAnchorPane;


    @FXML
    void myToggleButEventSB(MouseEvent event) {



        if (myToggleBut.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("is ON");
            Stage stage = (Stage) myAnchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        }else {
            System.out.println("is OFF");
            Stage stage = (Stage) myAnchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        }
    }


//    public void testingcopyaction(Scene scene){
//
//        ObservableList<Clip> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
//        scene.getAccelerators().put(copyCombination, () -> {
//            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
//                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
//                content.putString(list.getSelectedItem().getClip());
//                // original:
//                // content.putString(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getClip());
//                Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(content);
//            }
//        });
//
//
//    }
//
//    private static final KeyCodeCombination copyCombination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.C, KeyCombination.CONTROL_ANY);
//
//    private static final KeyCodeCombination pasteCombination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.V, KeyCodeCombination.CONTROL_ANY);


    // ------------------------- learned that copying from selected cell/item



//    public void updateview(){
//        ObservableList<Clip> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
//        ListView<String> mylistviewvar = new ListView<>(list);
//        String fromclipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString();
//
//
//
//        mylistviewvar.getItems().add(fromclipboard);
//
//
//
//    }


    @FXML
    private TextField searchFieldvar;

    public TextField getSearchFieldvar() {
        return searchFieldvar;
    }

    public void setSearchFieldvar(TextField searchFieldvar) {
        this.searchFieldvar = searchFieldvar;
    }

    @FXML
    void myonKeyTyped(KeyEvent event) {


     System.out.println("input changed");









//        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(mylistviewvar.getItems());
//
//        FilteredList<String> filteredList = new FilteredList<String>(list);
//        filteredList.setPredicate((e) -> true);
//
//        // ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(filteredList);
//
//
//
//        //TextField textField = new TextField();
//        searchFieldvar.textProperty().addListener((e) -> filteredList.setPredicate((v) -> (searchFieldvar.getText() == null || searchFieldvar.getText().length() == 0 || v.startsWith(searchFieldvar.getText()))));
//
//        mylistviewvar.setItems(filteredList);












//        FilteredList<String> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(mylistviewvar.getItems(), s -> true);
//
//        String filter = searchFieldvar.getText();
//
//      // System.out.println("changed");
//       if(filter == null || filter.length() == 0) {
//           filteredData.setPredicate(s -> true);
//       }
//       else {
//           filteredData.setPredicate(s -> s.contains(filter));
//       }

    }








    public void applyClipboardPolling() {
        ObservableList<Clip> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ListView<Clip> mylistviewvar = new ListView<>(list);

        final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        new com.sun.glass.ui.ClipboardAssistance(com.sun.glass.ui.Clipboard.SYSTEM) {
            @Override
            public void contentChanged() {
                // called every time system clipboard is changed
                // if the clipboard has a new String, add it to the TableView
                if (clipboard.hasString()) {

                    String toBeCopied = clipboard.getString();
                    // If the user hasn't selected anything in the table, we can safely add item
                    //
                    // If the user has selected something, and the selected clip differs from
                    // the String being copied, then we can add it.

                    // ObservableList<String> listview = FXCollections.observableArrayList("john","jane");
                    Clip clip = new Clip();
                    clip.setClip(clipboard.getString());
                    mylistviewvar.getItems().add(clip);


                    if (mylistviewvar.getSelectionModel().isEmpty() || !mylistviewvar.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getClip().equals(toBeCopied)) {
                        Clip clip1 = new Clip();
                        clip1.setClip(clipboard.getString());
                        Clip lastCopied = (mylistviewvar.getItems().size() > 1) ? mylistviewvar.getItems().get(mylistviewvar.getItems().size() - 1) : null;
                        if (lastCopied != null && lastCopied.getClip().equals(toBeCopied)) {
                            // sometimes the contentChanged() method is called without the
                            // content actually having changed, don't add in this case
                            return;
                        }
                        mylistviewvar.getItems().add(clip1);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }




   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

//       ClipboardListener listener = new ClipboardListener();
//       listener.setEntryListener(this);
//       listener.start();


      // FilteredList<String> filteredList = new FilteredList<String>(mylistviewvar.getItems());
      // filteredList.setPredicate((e) -> true);


       ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(mylistviewvar.getItems());

       FilteredList<String> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, s -> true);


       searchFieldvar.textProperty().addListener(obs->{

           String filter = searchFieldvar.getText();
           if(filter == null || filter.length() == 0) {
               filteredData.setPredicate(s -> true);
           }
           else {
               filteredData.setPredicate(s -> s.contains(filter));
           }
       });


















   }  //  initializable ends -------------------------------




//    @Override
//    public void onCopy(String data) {
//        mylistviewvar.getItems().add(0,  data);
//    }





} // Controller01 ends
```

**View.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="myAnchorPane" prefHeight="374.0" prefWidth="1188.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller.Controller01">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="myButton01" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="28.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#myButton01myEventClicked" text="Get clipboard type" />
      <ListView fx:id="mylistviewvar" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="133.0" prefHeight="229.0" prefWidth="561.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="searchFieldvar" layoutX="157.0" layoutY="89.0" onKeyTyped="#myonKeyTyped" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="297.0" />
      <TextArea layoutX="583.0" layoutY="133.0" prefHeight="229.0" prefWidth="591.0" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="myToggleBut" layoutX="526.0" layoutY="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#myToggleButEventSB" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="On Top" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you share your `Clip` class?

Comment: _I also want that same list to be updated/filtered when the user updates a textfield._ I don't think hundreds of lines of code are needed to demonstrate it. Please post [mre].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the posted code is very long. MRE is needed.

Comment: You are already using a `FilteredList` which works dynamically, updating its contents when the underlying observablelist is updated, so I am not sure what your issue is (I didn't read your code other than observing the user of FilteredList).  For minimal example, you could just get rid of fxml and controller, and all of the stuff to do with threads and clipboards, and just have a simple main app which uses observable lists and filtered lists to demonstrate the issue.  It wouldn't even need to have a UI necessarily, though a simple UI would be OK.

Comment: afaics, do did nothing of the requested changes (please read my earlier comment and act on every single suggestion :)

Comment: ahh ... just noticed that you did indeed read and acted, just not in this question ;) As a general rule, don't repost a question, instead, edit this .. if done correctly (your second looks like it might), this can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use a [`FilteredList<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) to filter what the `ListView` is showing:

```java
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("John", "Winston", "Viggo Tarasov", "Cassian", "Bowery King", "Sofia");

// You can add items from other sources to this list
ObservableList<String> sourceList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(names);

// Create a FilteredList with your source list
FilteredList<String> filteredNames = new FilteredList<>(sourceList);

// Bind the predicate property of the filtered list to the text field.
// The following line tells the list to update the filtered items when the text field's text changes
filteredNames.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> name -> name.contains(searchField.getText()), searchField.textProperty()));

// Use the filtered list in the list view
namesListView.setItems(filteredNames);
```