# How to dynamically filter a listview control using MVC while being updated in more than one way?

Tags: listview, javafx, model-view-controller, clipboard

I am a novice in JavaFX, I am using 3 files: **View.fxml**, **Main** and **Controller**.

I found how to update a ListView control with the string that is stored in the clipboard when the clipboard gets updated (when a string is copied) (thanks to the author [Java Clipboard listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098813/listening-on-system-clipboard-using-javafx/47550034))

What I have been unable to achieve is that I also want that same list to be updated/filtered when the user updates a text field. I am not sure how to setup the observable list, predicate or in which file, the Main file or in the Controller file.

I tried to improve the formatting as a previous question was closed/unable to be re-opened after I  edited.

The code from each file can be just copy/pasted, it runs (hopefully to show what I would like to achieve)

If you run into problems, adding VM options helps:

```
--module-path C:\Users\  ... \Documents\javafx-sdk-16\lib --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.swing,javafx.web,javafx.swt --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED
```

```
mylistviewvar.getItems()
```

If  `mylistviewvar` gets populated only when the program is running. How can I a feed this dynamically populating list to a FilteredList ?

Am I using the correct approch ? Can this be implemented using/inside a textchanged event:

```
@FXML
    void myonKeyTyped(KeyEvent event) {...
```

Here is the code:

**The code tries to get the listview updated when the user copies a string into the clipboard, and also when the user types/searched that same listview**

**Main**

```
package minimalsandbox;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application  {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader =new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/minimalsandbox/View.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.setX(200);
        primaryStage.setY(500);
        Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        double x = bounds.getMinX() + (bounds.getWidth() - scene.getWidth()) * 0.2;
        double y = bounds.getMinY() + (bounds.getHeight() - scene.getHeight()) * 0.55;
        primaryStage.setX(x);
        primaryStage.setY(y);

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //  in main, clipboard listener
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        final Clipboard systemClipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        new com.sun.glass.ui.ClipboardAssistance(com.sun.glass.ui.Clipboard.SYSTEM) {
            @Override
            public void contentChanged() {

                System.out.print("System clipboard content changed: ");
                if ( systemClipboard.hasImage() ) {
                    System.out.println("image");
                } else if ( systemClipboard.hasString() ) {
                    System.out.println("string");
                    //System.out.println(Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString());
                    System.out.println("current thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                    minimalsandbox.Controller controller = loader.getController();           // works1
                    String fromclipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString();
                    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); // does this `items` observable list gets re-generated every time the clipboard changes ?
                    controller.mylistviewvar.getItems().add(0,fromclipboard);                  // works1

                } else if ( systemClipboard.hasFiles() ) {
                    System.out.println("files");
                }
            }
        };
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println("crrent thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());


    }  // start stage ends --------------------------------------------

    public final minimalsandbox.Controller controller = new Controller();

} // Main ends
```

**Controller**

```
package minimalsandbox;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button myButton01;

    @FXML
    public ListView<String> mylistviewvar;

    public void setMylistviewvar(String listviewvar) {
        mylistviewvar.getItems().add(listviewvar);
    }

    @FXML
    void myButton01myEventClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hi there !");

        // to put string INTO clipboard
        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString("Some text");
        clipboard.setContent(content);
        // to copy from clipboard
        String fromclipboardstr = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString();
        System.out.println(fromclipboardstr);

    }  // button click ends
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton myToggleBut;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane myAnchorPane;

    @FXML
    void myToggleButEventSB(MouseEvent event) {

        if (myToggleBut.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("is ON");
            Stage stage = (Stage) myAnchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        }else {
            System.out.println("is OFF");
            Stage stage = (Stage) myAnchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private TextField searchFieldvar;

    public TextField getSearchFieldvar() {
        return searchFieldvar;
    }

    public void setSearchFieldvar(TextField searchFieldvar) {
        this.searchFieldvar = searchFieldvar;
    }

    //FilteredList<String> filteredNames = new FilteredList<>(mylistviewvar.getItems());

    @FXML
    void myonKeyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("input changed");
       // mylistviewvar.setItems(filteredNames);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {


        ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(mylistviewvar.getItems());
        FilteredList<String> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, s -> true);
        searchFieldvar.textProperty().addListener(obs->{

            String filter = searchFieldvar.getText();
            if(filter == null || filter.length() == 0) {
                filteredData.setPredicate(s -> true);
            }
            else {
                filteredData.setPredicate(s -> s.contains(filter));
            }
        });


    }  //  initializable ends -------------------------------


} // Controller ends
```

**View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="myAnchorPane" prefHeight="374.0" prefWidth="1188.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="minimalsandbox.Controller">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="myButton01" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="28.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#myButton01myEventClicked" text="Get clipboard type" />
        <ListView fx:id="mylistviewvar" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="133.0" prefHeight="229.0" prefWidth="561.0" />
        <TextField fx:id="searchFieldvar" layoutX="157.0" layoutY="89.0" onKeyTyped="#myonKeyTyped" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="297.0" />
        <TextArea layoutX="583.0" layoutY="133.0" prefHeight="229.0" prefWidth="591.0" />
        <ToggleButton fx:id="myToggleBut" layoutX="526.0" layoutY="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#myToggleButEventSB" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="On Top" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I can't compile this using my JavaFX version (because `com.sun.glass.ui` is not accessible. But is there a reason you are doing the initialization of the clipboard listener in `Main`, instead of in the obvious place (in `Controller.initialize()`)? The general pattern to use here is to set the filtered list as the items list for the list view, and update the underlying list (`data`) when you want to add/remove elements. (This was shown in the answer to your previous question.) Did you try that?

Comment: don't repost a question, instead edit the previous to make it answerable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I dynamically filter a listview control in javafx using the MVC model while is updated in more than one way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70211205/how-could-i-dynamically-filter-a-listview-control-in-javafx-using-the-mvc-model)

Comment: @kleopatra, I did edit it but is not answerable, I also wanted to delete it as the only answer was not helpful and comments did not build up knowledge but I was unable to do so.

Comment: @James_D appreciate the help, I did not know I had to intialize the listener in the Controller class, regarding the com.sun.glass.ui  I am using open jdk 16 and open javafx 16 also, I did try with azul and liberica but I remember finding an error.

I did not understand jewelsea comment until I read your first comment, I think I will try again and report back later.

Comment: You don't *have* to manage the clipboard functionality in the controller - you've already demonstrated that. It's just cleaner if you do so, because you don't have to expose stuff outside of the controller class. A better approach entirely would be to use an MVC approach. But the point is to use the `FilteredList` as the items list for the `ListView`, and modify (add/remove elements) the *underlying source list* for the `FilteredList`, however you delegate the responsibilities.